# How to use apoc.load.csv in conjunction with apoc.create.node

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I need to import a CSV file and create a node from each record. I am using APOC because supposedly I can use a column in the CSV file to define each node type as the nodes are created.

This doesn't work:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('FILE:///C:/Temp/Test/Test/Neo4jTest/import/Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv',{sep:","})  YIELD map
CALL apoc.create.node(['map.AttributeName'], {key:['map.NodeID']}) return count(*)
```

This is the error:

```
Procedure call inside a query does not support naming results implicitly (name explicitly using `YIELD` instead) (line 2, column 1 (offset: 124))
"CALL apoc.create.node(['map.AttributeName'], {key:['map.NodeID']}) return count(*)"
```

I also tried this syntax:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('FILE:///C:/Temp/Test/Test/Neo4jTest/import/Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv',{sep:","})  YIELD map
CALL apoc.create.node(map.AttributeName, {key:map.NodeID}) return count(*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try with this :

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('FILE:///C:/Temp/Test/Test/Neo4jTest/import/Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv',{sep:","})  YIELD map
CALL apoc.create.node(['map.AttributeName'], {key:['map.NodeID']}) YIELD node 
RETURN count(*)
```

I just add the `YIELD` stuff on the create node.

Cheers

Comment: That helped. I am now getting a data error so I don't think the query is doing what I think it should be doing. How do I get it to process each line in the CSV and create a node from that line?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a `YIELD node` after call `apoc.create.node` procedure. Try this:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('FILE:///C:/Temp/Test/Test/Neo4jTest/import/Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv',{sep:","}) YIELD map
CALL apoc.create.node(['map.AttributeName'], {key:['map.NodeID']}) YIELD node
return count(*)
```

Comment: That helped. I am now getting a data error so I don't think the query is doing what I think it should be doing. How do I get it to process each line in the CSV and create a node from that line?

Comment: Hello @nicomp. To answer this question is best to know how your data set looks like. Please, note that probably you are asking a new question in the comments. I recommend you make a new question showing a sample of your data set. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173312/how-do-i-fix-this-neo4j-apoc-query-that-creates-nodes-froma-csv-file