# How do I fix this Neo4j APOC query that creates nodes froma CSV file?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want the query to read the CSV file and create a node for each row in the file.

Here's the query:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('FILE:///C:/Temp/Test/Test/Neo4jTest/import/Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv',{sep:","})  YIELD map
CALL apoc.create.node(map.NodeType, {key:map.NodeID}) yield node return count(*)
```

Here's the error:

```
Can't coerce `RootNode` to List<String>
```

Here's the data file:

```
NodeType,NodeID,SchemaName,TableName,AttributeName,DataType,PreviousNodeID
RootNode,queryprocessingtest.q01.testfieldatablec ,queryprocessingtest,q01,testfieldatablec ,varchar,
Node,queryprocessingtest.qc.testfieldatablec ,queryprocessingtest,qc,testfieldatablec ,varchar,queryprocessingtest.q01.testfieldatablec 
Node,queryprocessingtest.ttablec.testfieldatablec ,queryprocessingtest,ttablec,testfieldatablec ,varchar,queryprocessingtest.q01.testfieldatablec
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of the `apoc.create.node` procedure must be an [array](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data).

So you need to convert the value of `map.NodeType` into an array:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('FILE:///C:/Temp/Test/Test/Neo4jTest/import/Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv',{sep:","})  YIELD map
CALL apoc.create.node([map.NodeType], {key:map.NodeID}) yield node return count(*)
```

Comment: So,  just add square brackets to the node type. Amazing. Thanks much. I have no idea where I would have found that info.

Comment: @nicomp if this answer has solved your problem, please, remember to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/360570) to mark this question as solved and to help another users of this site to find correct answers easily.