# Add label to node from a CSV file in NEO4J

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I am trying to add some nodes to my graph database from a CSV, which suppose is like:

```
    |  city         continent         feature_1 ...
    |--------------------------------------------------
0   |  Barcelona    Europe
1   |  Stockholm    Europe
2   |  New York     America
3   |  Nairobi      Africa
4   |  Tokyo        Asia
```

The first approach was to simply load this data as:

```
// Insert city nodes
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///city_data.csv' AS row
MERGE (city: City {name: row.city})
```

Next step was to incorporate the continent information, so I could have nodes of different colors. This means having two labels for each node, which is something I am not sure how to do. Anyway, for the moment I decided to simply have one label instead, which contained the continent information. Since this information is within the CSV file I believe `apoc.create.node` tool is the way to go. Hence, inspired by [How to use apoc.load.csv in conjunction with apoc.create.node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172733/how-to-use-apoc-load-csv-in-conjunction-with-apoc-create-node) I tried the following:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('file:///city_data.csv') YIELD row
CALL apoc.create.node(['row.continent'], {name:['row.continent']}) YIELD node 
RETURN count(*)
```

This does not raise any error, but it does something different from what I was thinking of. It basically sets the column name ("row.continent") itself as the label...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you surround the variable in apostrophes, so try this:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('file:///city_data.csv') YIELD row
CALL apoc.create.node([row.continent], {name: row.continent}) YIELD node 
RETURN count(*)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I realised there is some problem with using YIELD row. I better use YIELD map instead.